# What do you call someone who doesn't know how to swim?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there one word for someone who does not know how to swim?

Even better if there is one word for someone who doesn't know how to swim but dives to save a drowning person?

If no, then suggest a similar phrase.

Comment: *Aquatically-challenged*? The jumper could be call *fool*? (Okay, *heroic fool*)

Comment: Related: What do you call someone who does not know how to swim? a: Bob.

Comment: A potential drowner.  Just kidding.

Answer (score 12):

The word or someone who cannot or does not swim is [*non-swimmer*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/non-swimmer).

I am not aware of a word for a non-swimmer who dives into try to save a drowning person. I would call them a [hindrance](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hindrance) or "a danger to themselves and others", as they will only make things worse and will mean that rescuers need to save two people, not one.

Comment: Either that, or, if you're more of an optimist, you could call the diver a _fast learner_.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-slang-word-for-someone-who-doesnt-know-how-to-swim), the word "**landlubber**" can be used (mainly by older people) as slang for someone who can't swim, and "**the Rock Squad**" is US military slang for such people.

You should be careful when using Matt E Ellen's [suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/128490/87724) of "non-swimmer", since this word can also be used in a racist sense - see [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=non-swimmer).

Comment: Urban Dictionary is mostly completely made-up words invented on the spot by users. No reason to believe that "non-swimmer" is racist just because UD says so.